# Create a contact in a non-default Outlook contact folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook-2010

I would like  to create a contact in a non-default Outlook contact folder with Excel VBA 2010.

In this example, the folder name is “azerty”,  located in
\mypersonnal_pst\Contacts

I tried:

```
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Parent.Folders("azerty")
Set objContact = myolApp.CreateItem(olContactItem)
With objContact
  .Email1Address = "example@ex.com "
  .FirstName = "Joe"
  .LastName = "Mc"
  .HomeTelephoneNumber = "99 99 99 99 99"
  .HomeAddressCity = "Xlcity"
  .Save
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create an Outlook item in the specific folder use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Items class instead.

```
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Parent.Folders("azerty")
Set objContact = Folder.Items.Add(olContactItem)
With objContact
  .Email1Address = "example@ex.com "
  .FirstName = "Joe"
  .LastName = "Mc"
  .HomeTelephoneNumber = "99 99 99 99 99"
  .HomeAddressCity = "Xlcity"
  .Save
End With
```

Or move the item to the target folder using the [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869633(v=office.15).aspx) method after creation.

```
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Set myolApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = myolApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Parent.Folders("azerty")
Set objContact = myolApp.CreateItem(olContactItem)
With objContact
  .Email1Address = "example@ex.com "
  .FirstName = "Joe"
  .LastName = "Mc"
  .HomeTelephoneNumber = "99 99 99 99 99"
  .HomeAddressCity = "Xlcity"
  .Save
  .Move Folder 
End With
```

You can read more about that in the [How To: Create a new Outlook Contact item programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/07/outlook-create-contact-item/) article.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene; but to proper functioning, after declare:
`Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder` 
To use it, instead of:
`Set objContact = Folder.Add(olContactItem)`
It has to be:
`Set objContact = Folder.items.Add(olContactItem)`

Comment: Corrected. Thank you.