# Send invites for share folder Items

Tags: vba, outlook

We use the following code to create a number of items in a shared calendar. Everything works out, only the invites are not send to the optional attendees. Unfortunately the MS Docs are a bit unclear in this area:

```
Sub DoOne(Calendar, Subject, Start, Duration, Category)
Dim Appointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim Attendee As Outlook.Recipient


If Subject <> "" Then
    Set Appointment = Calendar.Items.Add
    With Appointment
        .Start = Start
        .Duration = Duration
        .ReminderSet = False
        
        .Subject = Subject
        .Categories = Category
        
      
    Set Attendee = Appointment.Recipients.Add("distrubutionlist")
    Attendee.Type = olOptional
            
    Appointment.Move Calendar
    Appointment.Send

End If
End Sub
```

Also tried this with the property OptionalAttendees.Add but also there no invites are generated.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the meeting status for the appointment first by using the [AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.meetingstatus) property which sets an `OlMeetingStatus` constant specifying the meeting status of the appointment.

```
Sub CreateAppt() 
 Dim myItem As Object
 Dim myRequiredAttendee, myOptionalAttendee, myResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 
 myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting 
 myItem.Subject = "Strategy Meeting" 
 myItem.Location = "Conference Room B" 
 myItem.Start = #9/24/2020 1:30:00 PM# 
 myItem.Duration = 90 
 Set myRequiredAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired 
 Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Kevin Kennedy") 
 myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional 
 Set myResourceAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Conference Room B")
 myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Also, you need to pay special attention to the `Move` method which is called right before the `Send` one. It moves a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder and returns an Object value that represents the item that has been moved to the designated folder. So, your code shouldn't call the `Move` method or handle it gracefully:

```
movedItem = Appointment.Move Calendar
movedItem.Send
```

Answer (score 0):

With these two changes worked, thanks, Eugene.

The working code reads:

```
Sub DoOne(Calendar, Subject, Start, Duration, Category)

Dim Appointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim Attendee As Outlook.Recipient


If Subject <> "" Then
    Set Appointment = Calendar.Items.Add
    With Appointment
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
        .Start = Start
        .Duration = Duration
        .ReminderSet = False
        
        .Subject = Subject
        .Categories = Category
    End With

    Set Attendee = Appointment.Recipients.Add("distributionlist")
    Attendee.Type = olOptional
    Attendee.Resolve

    Appointment.Send

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: fyi. No change needed as this is a non-fatal error. You Add the appointment to the Calendar so it is not necessary to Move. Moving can be appropriate if the appointment is not added but "created". Created items are placed in the appropriate default folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326940/create-a-contact-in-a-non-default-outlook-contact-folder

Comment: But I add the appointment to my own calender not the shared one, do I?

Comment: As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331780/1571407, `Add` is for a referenced folder. The appointment is already where you want it to be. Put a `Debug.Print Appointment.Parent` after `Set Appointment = Calendar.Items.Add` and as well after `Set Appointment = Appointment.Move(Calendar)`. The result should be the same.